# i am not able to run a import export functionality in django 2.2.5

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-import-export

**I want to import export option in Django admin panel  data import and export**

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html

also, try with this example

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html

```
python 3.7
django 2.2.5
django-import-export 1.2.0
```

> settings.py

```
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True


models Person
```

> resource.py

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Person

class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

> admin.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources

from .models import Person, Pravacy_check

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
# Register your models here.

class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PersonResource



admin.site.register(PersonAdmin)
```

all app modules data import and export need to work prefect.

Comment: Please format your code to be properly displayed. How exactly are you unable to run this? Does it fail to run at all, does it throw an error, does it fail to produce an excepted affect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person    # 

from import_export import resources

from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):   # FOR ADMIN IMPORT EXPORT ONLY 
    pass


admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)   #  FOR ADMIN IMPORT EXPORT ONLY
```

Settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'import_export',
        'app',


    ]
```

Comment: ** All are correct as of no from your code **
`
RemovedInDjango30Warning at /admin/accounts/person/import/
{% load admin_static %} is deprecated in favor of {% load static %}.

Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: RemovedInDjango30Warning
Exception Value: 
{% load admin_static %} is deprecated in favor of {% load static %}. 

{% load admin_static %} is deprecated in favor of {% load static %}.
`

Comment: Please post question with full detail .

Comment: ** still not working I think the issue with package and python version